# Paste bash command, but make sure it doesn't run

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

Sometimes when you <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> with bash it will run the command even though you didn't intend to run it yet - is there a way to paste a command into the bash shell / terminal making sure you don't actually run any of the command(s)?

if you could set what was on the terminal prompt programmatically, you could do this with bash on MacOS:

```
export BASH_PROMPT="$(pbpaste)"
```

which ties into my other question that I just asked:
[How to change the value that's in the prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56606787/how-to-change-the-value-thats-in-the-prompt)

Comment: AIUI bracketed paste mode does this (in bash v4.4 and later), but I can't find good documentation on it. See [here](https://github.com/Aaronmsv/PastejackingProtection/issues/4) for basic info.

Answer (score 4):

There is a Readline variable:

> [**`enable-bracketed-paste`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-enable_002dbracketed_002dpaste)
>   When set to `On`, Readline will configure the terminal in a way that will enable it to insert each paste into the editing buffer as a single string of characters, instead of treating each character as if it had been read from the keyboard. This can prevent pasted characters from being interpreted as editing commands. The default is `off`.

To turn this on, put something like

```
set enable-bracketed-paste on
```

into your `~/.inputrc`.

This was introduced in Bash 4.4 / Readline 7.0.

Comment: Is there a way to write to the editing buffer programmatically?

Comment: @AlexanderMills The only time I'm aware of this happening is when you run an autocompletion function, where you have the `COMP_LINE` variable that contains the current command line - but I don't think you can set it, only read from it.

Answer (score 2):

Use ^X^E aka Ctrl+X Ctrl+E in bash to open your $EDITOR for command entry.

Paste and/or edit as much as you want, across as many lines as you want. When you're done, save and exit, and bash will run it.

(In `vi` mode, the shortcut is `v`)

Comment: so I guess writing to `$EDITOR` will set the prompt command which is an answer to the linked question in the OP? Maybe it can be done more programmatically like I indicated in the OP?

Comment: I am looking to do this programmatically like with a script that doesn't involve human interaction mmkay

Comment: Which bash shell do you run that lets you use ^V to paste? I've only seen that on windows, and not in bash on windows.

Comment: If you want to paste commands into a shell without risking running them too soon, this is how. If you want to do something else, please edit your question to reflect that

Comment: This is *not* safe in many editor/terminal combinations. See [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355620/3645), [2](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39118/1220), [3](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/dYfZp7tMg5c).